# YOLO обучение на процессоре

Tags: linux, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, cuda, машинное-зрение

обучал раньше YOLO на гугл колаб, но так как время там ограниченно, а количество файлов увеличилось и времени на обучение не хватает, появилась задача развернуть обучение на сервере на линуксе, где нет ГПУ и cuda, только процессор.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Да также всё почти. Только учиться будет долго. Вы сначала попробуйте запустить, а там видно будет что поправить по ошибкам.

Comment: Если оно написано на Tensorflow 1.0 и в нем есть ядра, написанные только на CUDA, вам предстоит увлекательный квест по переписыванию их на C++.

В остальных случаях, все должно завестись само, но работать будет в сотни раз медленнее ( один GPU примерно в 250 раз быстрее одного ядра  CPU)